# Dynamically change ehcache configuration

Tags: ehcache

I want to dynamically change the configuration of the EhCache instance we're using, specifically the maxElementsInMemory setting. We are using EhCache 1.5 and I can see that it is possible API-wise:

```
cache.getCacheConfiguration().setMaxElementsInMemory(num);
```

But the documentation of EhCache says:

> After a Cache has been started its
>   configuration is not generally
>   changeable. However, since Ehcache
>   2.0, certain aspects of cache configuration can modified dynamically
>   at runtime...

So my question is: can I use this API in EhCache 1.5 or is it not guaranteed to work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are only certain properties you can modify (see [Modifying Ehcache configuration at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441606/modifying-ehcache-configuration-at-runtime)), maxElementsInMemory should be one of them... for me that works in ehcache 2.4!

Answer (score 0):

As per Ehcache 2.8, this is possible:

```
Cache cache = manager.getCache("sampleCache");
CacheConfiguration config = cache.getCacheConfiguration();
config.setTimeToIdleSeconds(60);
config.setTimeToLiveSeconds(120);
config.setmaxEntriesLocalHeap(10000);
config.setmaxEntriesLocalDisk(1000000);
```

source:
http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/configuration/configuration#dynamically-changing-cache-configuration