# Modifying Ehcache configuration at runtime

Tags: java, spring, ehcache, terracotta

I am using ehcache in Spring framework. I am using ehcache.xml to initialize ehcache. However I want to add certain properties such as terracottaconfig at runtime. For this purpose I overridden the class EhCacheManagerFactoryBean. Currently I am overriding method getObject() of this class (I don't know whether this is a correct one to override as other method setResource() and afterPropertiesSet() are called before class is initialized with ehcache.xml file.)

This is my spring configuration file

```
<bean id="cacheManager"
class="com.dexknows.util.CustomEhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
<property name="configLocation">
   <value>file:///${vp_data_dir}/ehcache.xml</value>
</property>     
<property name="terracottaConfigUrl" value="#{dexProperties['terracottaConfig.Url']}"/>
</bean>
```

and this is the class method that I overridden

```
public class CustomEhCacheManagerFactoryBean extends EhCacheManagerFactoryBean {

    private String terracottaConfigUrl;
    private Resource resourceConfiguration;

    @Override
    public void setConfigLocation(Resource configLocation) {            
        super.setConfigLocation(configLocation);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws IOException, CacheException {

        super.afterPropertiesSet();
    }


    @Override
    public CacheManager getObject() {

        CacheManager manager = super.getObject();

        TerracottaClientConfiguration terracottaClientConfiguration = new TerracottaClientConfiguration();
        terracottaClientConfiguration.setRejoin(true);
        terracottaClientConfiguration.setUrl(terracottaConfigUrl);



        manager.getConfiguration().setDynamicConfig(true);
        manager.getConfiguration().terracotta(terracottaClientConfiguration);

Configuration().terracotta(terracottaClientConfiguration)));
    return manager;

    }

    public String getTerracottaConfigUrl() {
        return terracottaConfigUrl;
    }

    public void setTerracottaConfigUrl(String terracottaConfigUrl) {
        this.terracottaConfigUrl = terracottaConfigUrl;
    }

}
```

I am getting following exception:

Error creating bean with name 'cacheManager': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: net.sf.ehcache.config.Configuration.dynamicConfig can't be changed dynamically

I have set dynamicConfig="true"

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd"
         updateCheck="false"
         monitoring="autodetect"
         dynamicConfig="true"
         name="xyz">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After analyzing the source code of EhCacheManagerFactoryBean class, I found that 'terracottaConfigConfiguration' can't be changed dynamically. **Only properties mentioned in enum DynamicProperty can be changed dynamically**. Still, If some one find the documentation, mentioning the same, it will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There are only a few dynamic properties:

- `timeToIdleSeconds`
- `timeToLiveSeconds`
- `maxElementsInMemory`
- `maxElementsOnDisk`

They are mentioned in the official [Javadocs of `net.sf.ehcache.config.CacheConfiguration`](http://ehcache.org/apidocs/net/sf/ehcache/config/CacheConfiguration.html) ("Dynamic Configuration").